# Passing tor proxy to splash in WSL2

Tags: tor, wsl-2, scrapy-splash

I'm currently trying to pass a proxy to a splash instance running on docker Desktop launched from WSL.
I start tor using `sudo service tor start`.

To make sure my WSL tor service is communicating with Windows, I passed it as proxy to Firefox with the following Parameters:

- IP: 127.0.0.1
- Port: 9050
- Proxy Type: SOCKS5

Then I go to https://check.torproject.org/ and tadaa **it works**.

I run my container using the following command:
`sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 -p 5023:5023 scrapinghub/splash --disable-browser-caches`

The easiest way I found to test it was to go to `localhost:8050` and type in the following lines:

```
  splash:on_request(function(request)
    request:set_proxy{
      host = "127.0.0.1",
      port = 9050,
      username = "",
      password = "",
      type = "SOCKS5"
    }
  end
  )
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

I query https://check.torproject.org/ , and I get error 99.

Am I missing something important here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [proxy profiles](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=proxy#proxy-profiles)? They look to be the preferred way to attach proxies with a docker Splash container.